# SQL Server 2005 php 5.2

Tags: php, sql-server-2005, iis-6, windows-server-2003

I'm having a really difficult time trying to get php to connect to SQL Server 2005.  It seems like no matter what I do or what page I visit, I either get the wrong extension/driver or find a dead link.  The most recent attempt was php_sqlsrv_52_ts_vc6.dll which apparently doesn't support anything prior to 2008.

After over two days of searching, I'm lost, and upgrading either php or SQL Server is not an option unfortunately...

EDIT:
Everything is running on IIS 6 - Server 2003 (Same box).

Comment: This is on a windows box?  I think if you're using PHP 5.2, it should "just work" - http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mssql.php.  On an older version of PHP (I think 5.0...) I used MSSQL with no problems whatsoever. [Edit again] did you see this: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mssql.requirements.php ?

Comment: @Aerik my php didn't have the mssql.dll so I added it to the ext folder and the php.ini, then I recycled my server's Application Pools (restart).  For some reason it isn't working though.  I'm pretty sure I did everything correct as I'm not a php noob, just a IIS and MSSQL noob.  phpinfo() has no mention of mssql anywhere...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem probably is that you are running IIS6, which will require the **nts**-version.

Additionally you have to install the SQL Server Native Client 2008, which is a bit misleading as it will still work with MSSQL 2005.

It should go something like this:

1. Download SQL Server Driver 2.0 for PHP
2. Place the dll (5.2 nts) into PHP's ext-folder
3. Enable the extension in the php.ini `extension=sqlsrv*.dll`
4. Install a recent version of Microsoft's Native Client (e.g. from the SQL Server 2012 Feature Pack)
5. Restart your web server.

I use Apache, so I'm not sure if there is anything else to do on IIS or whether some of the steps differ, but this is how I got it working.

Comment: So it's non-thread safe, thanks.  Still didn't solve my issue, but I'm sure that was a blocker.

Comment: @jreed121 I added a step by step-instruction to my answer. Hope that helps. If not, please edit your question with additional infos on what's wrong.

Comment: Thanks, I'm just kind of skeptical of installing the native client since it's an important production server.

Comment: I bit the bullet and installed the Native Cleint and it worked! My problem was that the php installed is TS...